# Replace letters with arbitrary numbers in SQL aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id |  subject  | grade |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | english   | 2     |
|  1 | math      | 3     |
|  1 | physics   | 1     |
|  1 | chemistry | 1     |
|  1 | biology   | *     |
|  2 | english   | 1     |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

I'd like to run a

```
AVG(grade) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id DESC) AS 'Average Grade'
```

But of course will not work as there are grades that are *, A, B, etc.

Is there a way I can tell the AVG to replace the letters with arbitrary values in its calculation like

*. `*` = 0

*. A = 1

*. B = 2

AND ignore fields like N/A or X.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

My DBMS is Sql Server

Comment: What' s your dbms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` in `AVG` function.

```
AVG(CASE WHEN grade = '*' THEN 0 
     WHEN grade = 'A' THEN 1 
     WHEN grade = 'B' THEN 2 
     ....
    ELSE grade END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id DESC) AS 'Average Grade'
```

**NOTE**

I would suggest you let `grade` be int dataType instead of the string, because that can easier to calculate.

Comment: Thanks I did not know you could put a `CASE WHEN` inside an aggregate function. I added a `WHEN GRADE <> '*' and ISNUMERIC(grade) <> 1 THEN NULL` to make it ignore other fields that I did not specify like N/A or X. Now I was going to cast as a float so I could get an accurate average like `AVG(CAST(grade AS FLOAT)` but now with the case inside it I'm not so sure where to put the cast anymore. Tried `AVG(CAST(CASE WHEN... ELSE grade END AS FLOAT)` and `CAST(AVG(CASE WHEN... AS FLOAT)` but neither worked. Any ideas? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use a giant `case` expression as part of the `avg()`.  However, I would suggest that you have a reference table or at least a derived table to handle the mapping:

Second `(partition by id order by id)` does not make sense.  Either you want the complete average for `id` (my guess) or you want a running average.  So,

```
select avg(v.grade_val) over (partition by t.id) as id_average_grade
from t outer apply
     (select 
      from (values ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('*', 0), ('1', 1), ('2', 2), . . .
           ) v(grade, grade_val)
      where v.grade = t.grade
     ) v(grade_val)
```

Note that the inner `values()` could be a *bona fide* reference table.